# Модальное окно на jQuery

Tags: jquery

Доброго всем.

Вот [исходник модального окна](http://jsfiddle.net/g7yae/2/). Там чтобы я не менял, whidth и height окна остаётся неизменным (class iframe). Как изменять его размеры?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.gallery, a.iframe").fancybox();
    $("a.modalbox").fancybox({
        "frameWidth": 400,
        "frameHeight": 400
    });
    $("a.gallery2").fancybox({
        "padding": 20,
        // отступ контента от краев окна 
        "imageScale": false,
        // Принимает значение true - контент(изображения) масштабируется по размеру окна, или false - окно вытягивается по размеру контента. По умолчанию - TRUE 
        "zoomOpacity": false,
        // изменение прозрачности контента во время анимации (по умолчанию false) 
        "zoomSpeedIn": 1000,
        // скорость анимации в мс при увеличении фото (по умолчанию 0) 
        "zoomSpeedOut": 1000,
        // скорость анимации в мс при уменьшении фото (по умолчанию 0) 
        "zoomSpeedChange": 1000,
        // скорость анимации в мс при смене фото (по умолчанию 0) 
        "frameWidth": 700,
        // ширина окна, px (425px - по умолчанию) 
        "frameHeight": 600,
        // высота окна, px(355px - по умолчанию) 
        "overlayShow": true,
        // если true затеняят страницу под всплывающим окном. (по умолчанию true). Цвет задается в jquery.fancybox.css - div#fancy_overlay   
        "overlayOpacity": 0.8,
        // Прозрачность затенения (0.3 по умолчанию) 
        "hideOnContentClick": false,
        // Если TRUE закрывает окно по клику по любой его точке (кроме элементов навигации). Поумолчанию TRUE   
        "centerOnScroll": false // Если TRUE окно центрируется на экране, когда пользователь прокручивает страницу   
    });
    $("#menu a, .anim").hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            "paddingLeft": "10px"
        }, 300)
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            "paddingLeft": "0"
        }, 300);
    });
    $("a.iframe").fancybox({
        "frameWidth": 1200,
        // ширина окна, px (425px - по умолчанию) 
        "frameHeight": 900 // высота окна, px(355px - по умолчанию)   
    });
});
```

-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.krasnoyarsk.front.ru/fancybox/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.krasnoyarsk.front.ru/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css"
media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.krasnoyarsk.front.ru/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.krasnoyarsk.front.ru/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.2.4.pack.js"></script>

<a class="iframe" title="Простая HTML" href="http://www.ya.ru">ya.ru</a>
```

Comment: О, млин! Кто кто-то из юзеров тут ругается за приведение исходного когда (мол копипастить лень), а тут наоборот добавили сами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы бы еще больше подключений сделали ))) [Смотрите пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/g7yae/4/), изменяйте на здоровье.

```
<a class="iframe" title="Простая HTML" href="http://www.ya.ru">ya.ru</a>
```

-

```
$("a.iframe").fancybox({
     "frameWidth" : 400,
     "frameHeight" : 500
});
```

P.S. *Оффтоп.* На будущее - на jsFiddle, лучше подключайте внешние JS/CSS файлы тут:
[image]

И не нужно подключать саму библиотеку. Достаточно выбрать версию из списка.

Comment: та да, подключений просто тьма)

Comment: Ага, недавно только использовать стал, учусть только :)
Спасибо! всё работает :), я и думал, что там и галлерея и прочее, думал что это как одна единая библиотека...